# How to create an interface with for blog post with options,bold/ italic in django blog

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am creating a blog using django and in between I found that my blog posts aren't arranged properly like no paragraphs,links,an option to add in between images and just every thing is random.

I would to know if there is way of cleaning the post by making it to have paragraphs or headings like the interface in the picture:

[image: see image]

Comment: have you searched for an answer to this question? "wysiwyg editor + django" should get you a long way.

Comment: One plugin you can use is django-ckeditor https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/